# With Rails 5, where to create a background job method which can also be used by a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create a method that will create a rankings list of all my users (query for all users, calculate their points and then store the rankings in the database).

I need this to happen in a background job.

I also need the ability to run this method via a Rails controller method.

With Rails 5, where should I store this file/task/job in my Rails app and how do I then call this method in my controller, outside of my background job task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically create a job like you normaly would and then you can call in in your controller

This is straight from the Rails docs:

create a job

```
bin/rails generate job guests_cleanup
```

define your job

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*guests)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

execute your job

```
GuestsCleanupJob.perform_later guest
```

You can read more in the rails docs:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html